# In Visual Studio is there a way to show both up and down (left and right) arrows in the finder at the same time?

Tags: visual-studio

I want to click back and forth, without using keyboard commands and without first clicking the down arrow to reveal one or the other. I just want to see both arrows at once.
[image: Example of current undesirable layout.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot do what you want with the Find window in the current 15.9.x version of Visual Studio 2017.

However, if you hit `<Ctrl><Shift>-F`, you will see the Find and Replace window. If you set **Look in** to **Current Document**, then it will behave just like the Find window--except this window displays **Find Previous** and **Find Next** buttons--exactly what you want.

[image]